# Como saber en que posición se encuentra un determinado digito en python

Tags: python

tengo la siguiente lista por ejemplo:
numeros=[1234,5267,5648,8934]. Quisiera saber de que manera puedo identificar a los números cuyo tercer digito sea 3.

Comment: Que intentaste hasta ahora para resolverlo? Podrías editar la pregunta y agregarlo por favor? De ese modo tu pregunta será mejor recibida y no parecerá del tipo "haganme la tarea".

Comment: hola, he intentado con la funcion .split() pasando como parametro el numero 3 y luego evaluando si la longitud es =1 pero me surge un error puesto que split es para cadenas y no para numeros

Comment: Pon el código que has usado hasta ahora! Un ejemplo ejecutable, o al menos las líneas donde sucede lo que quieres hacer y no sale!

Comment: @M.K No siempre alcanza con las lineas donde sucede el problema. Se requiere que el ejemplo sea minimo, completo y verificable.

Comment: Quería poner eso, pero al poner las palabras "ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable", deberías linkar a la página de SO que especifíca lo que es mínimo, completo y verificable. Para ponerlo como tu, donde el usuario puede no entender lo que dices, prefiero no ponerlo! Pero gracias! @DanteS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo ideal sería hacer un casteo a `string` de los números, y ahí comprobar si existe!

Siempre pon código en las preguntas que hagas (preguntas de este estilo al menos). Sin haber visto nada de tu código, esto es una idea:

```
    digito = 3
    for num in numeros:
        if '3' in str(num)[digito]:
            print('{} True'.format(num))
        else:
            print("False")
```